# Fill form based on dynamic data on reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying a very simple thing to implement that is `useState` hook to change a form filed.The form field contains a product name which is brought after api call.And after api call i want to set the name in form value but its not working.Lets jump into the code below

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Form, Input} from 'antd'
const Product = () => {
    const [name, setname] = useState('')
    //get data from api call here
    useEffect(() => {
        //or get data from api call here
        setname(apidata.name)
        console.log(apidata.name) //It prints name in console
    })
    return(
        <Form>
            <Input value={name} onChange={e => setname(e.target.value)} /> //But here i cant get value
        </Form>
    )
}
export default Product
```

Above is marked with comments where my code not works even if i hard code name in useEffect like `setname('mabuhay')` its not working.

N.B: I am using `apollo-react` `useQuery` to get data from `graphql api` & First response returns empty object

Comment: for rendering JSX you have to import `React` itself, `import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'`, another thing, from where do you import `Input`? because basically `value` should chain input field with the value passed in

Comment: @HagaiHarari imported but no improvement and its a functional component.so importing React is not too important

Comment: @HagaiHarari i am using ant design.Input is from there

Comment: Apart from the fact that you are not importing `React`, your code is functional, see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-986h7). Note that with `apidata` not being an outer scope constant, you would have to include it as a dep to `useEffect`

Comment: @Hyetigran first log is empty 2nd log prints the name

Comment: You are either not showing us the entire code or something else is fundamentally wrong unrelated to this component. I replicated the above code and [it's working](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-986h7?file=/demo.js).

Comment: The problem is that you said even if you hard coded `setname('mabuhay')` i don't know how is that even possible

Comment: @HassanAzzam yes thats my qstn also.it works if i only do this : `const [ name, setname] = useState('Mabuhuay')`

Comment: Ok, can you remove the code the fetch data from the API completely and try to use `setname('some name')` inside the `useEffect` and see if this works ?

Comment: @HassanAzzam i tried this : `useEffect(() => {
        setProductname('Towel')
        console.log(productname)
    })` but first log is undefined and 2nd log is 'towel

Comment: the first log because you're not using the second parameter for `useEffect` you should add an empty array `[]`.
but since it does work then there's something wrong in you're API query and the problem is not in react.
unless you share the full component code with the query i don't think we can figure it out.

Comment: @HassanAzzam .If i set second parameter it logs undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217131/discussion-between-tick-twitch-and-hassan-azzam).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty array in your useeffect, I think it's being called everytime you set a value for name that's why nothing is happening

```
useEffect(() => {
  setname(apidata.name)
  console.log(apidata.name)
}, [])
```

Comment: Empty Array does not log anything

Comment: @TickTwitch from what I understood you got a value from an api, set `name` value to what you got and then just want to type something in the input field?

Comment: I want to set value as initial value.